On the Internet I found a claim of no self in a sutra. Is it true?

the Aṣṭā­daśa­sāhasrikā­prajñā­pāramitā:
Furthermore, Subhūti, you should know that a sentient being is nonexistent because a self is nonexistent. You should know that a living being, a creature, one who lives, an individual, a person, one born of Manu, a child of Manu, one who does, one who feels, one who knows, and one who sees is nonexistent because a sentient being is nonexistent. You should know that the very limit of reality is nonexistent because … one who knows and one who sees is nonexistent. You should know that space is nonexistent because the very limit of reality is nonexistent. You should know that the Great Vehicle is nonexistent because space is nonexistent. You should know that the infinite, the countless, and that which is beyond measure [F.201.b] are nonexistent because the Great Vehicle is nonexistent, and you should know that all dharmas are nonexistent because that which is beyond measure is nonexistent. Therefore, Subhūti, the Great Vehicle has room for infinite, countless beings beyond measure. And why? Subhūti, it is because a self, up to one who knows and one who sees, the very limit of reality, space, the Great Vehicle, the infinite, the countless, that which is beyond measure, up to all dharmas all cannot be apprehended.
And why? Subhūti, bodhisattva great beings practicing the perfection of wisdom do not see form; do not see feeling, perception, volitional factors, or consciousness; do not see eyes; do not see ears, nose, tongue, body, or thinking mind; do not see a form, a sound, a smell, a taste, a feeling, or a dharma; do not see ignorance; do not see volitional factors, consciousness, name and form, the six sense fields, contact, feeling, craving, appropriation, existence, birth, or old age and death; do not see greed; do not see hatred or confusion; do not see a self; do not see a being, a living being, one who lives, an individual, a person, one born of Manu, a child of Manu, one who does, one who feels, one who knows, or one who sees; do not see the desire realm; do not see the form realm or formless realm; do not see śrāvakas and the śrāvaka dharmas; do not see pratyekabuddhas and the pratyekabuddha dharmas; do not see bodhisattvas and do not see bodhisattva dharmas; do not see buddhas [F.68.b] and do not see buddha dharmas; do not see awakening, up to do not see all dharmas. And while not seeing all dharmas they do not tremble, feel frightened, or become terrified.”

My question is : Are all sentient beings non existent as the sutra claims ?

It's probably just a bad translation. You're quoting from an English translation of a Tibetan translation of a relatively late Sanskrit text. A lot can go wrong in each translation.

@blue_ego what is reality ?

using the word reality here

@blue_eggo lost the context here.

In the context of Prajñāpāramitā literature all such statements are qualified. The texts seek to describe and reflect on a (temporary) state in which there is no sensory experience (śūnyatā "absence"; aka nirvāṇā "extinction").
In that state of absence (śūnyatāyām), there is no awareness of self. Since one is not aware of anything, one is, ipso facto, not aware of self.
Outside that state, it's another story. Outside that state, even the awakened can follow a conversation and know who said what and whose turn it is to talk. They are aware of themselves as distinct from us. Or they would be constantly confused. It's just that we should not draw metaphysical conclusions from this observation. Just because you are not aware of something, doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.
But as I commented above, you are citing an English translation of a Tibetan translation of a Sanskrit text. You simply cannot rely on such texts to accurately reflect the beliefs of Buddhists.
It is quite true (as others have bent over backwards to point out) that early Buddhists avoided the conclusion that because a self is not evident, it doesn't exist.
But it is also true that later Buddhists reified the concept and did state that self doesn't exist. And it is also true that many Buddhists came to the view that self does exist.
The point of the Prajñāpāramitā is that sensory experience is not a reliable guide to metaphysics. Any metaphysical conclusions based on sensory experience are apt to be unreliable, in much the same way and for much the same reasons that a translation of a translation of text is unreliable.
So the best conclusion, no matter what anyone else or any text says, is that statements about existence and non-existence (i.e. metaphysical statements) are bound to be unreliable given the epistemic apparatus afforded us by evolution. Any discussion of existence/non-existence is pretty pointless.
The point is not to think about self in any particular way. Self is quite irrelevant to those who undergo cessation and absence. The point is to practice anupalambhayoga "the practice of nonapprehension" in order to bring sensory experience to a halt. It's only in that state that one gains the goals of Buddhism.

Then I completely misunderstood the purpose of those texts, not that I've read much -- I thought they were metaphysical (and therefore an intellectual digression). But this answer is saying they are more about "cessation" -- like the early Buddhist texts? -- and anti-metaphysical.

Yes. Until there is a decent English translation it's best to study them in Sanskrit. Or not at all.


Then Ven. Ananda went to the Blessed One and on arrival, having bowed
down to him, sat to one side. As he was sitting there he said to the
Blessed One, "It is said that the world is empty, the world is empty,
lord. In what respect is it said that the world is empty?"
"Insofar as it is empty of a self or of anything pertaining to a self:
Thus it is said, Ananda, that the world is empty. And what is empty of
a self or of anything pertaining to a self? The eye is empty of a self
or of anything pertaining to a self. Forms... Eye-consciousness...
Eye-contact is empty of a self or of anything pertaining to a self.
"The ear is empty...
"The nose is empty...
"The tongue is empty...
"The body is empty...
"The intellect is empty of a self or of anything pertaining to a self.
Ideas... Intellect-consciousness... Intellect-contact is empty of a
self or of anything pertaining to a self. Thus it is said that the
world is empty."
Suñña Sutta: Empty


I can understand the Sunna sutta but where does he say all beings are non existent?

"Being does not arise, since it exists. Non-being does not arise, since it does not exist. Being and non-being [together] do not arise, due to [their] heterogeneity. Consequently they do not endure or vanish." @SacrificialEquation

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/51362/8157

from SN 5.10:

Why now do you assume 'a being'?
Mara, have you grasped a view?
This is a heap of sheer constructions:
Here no being is found.
Just as, with an assemblage of parts,
The word 'chariot' is used,
So, when the aggregates are present,
There's the convention 'a being.'
It's only suffering that comes to be,
Suffering that stands and falls away.
Nothing but suffering comes to be,
Nothing but suffering ceases.

In this famous sutta the nun Vajira catches the Mara and argues that "a living being" is merely a convention applied on account of the aggregates. In the ultimate analysis there's no 'being" to be found, only the dukkha arising and ceasing.

Suppose being is just a convention and not a practical concept then if I break the leg of a dog and it starts crying,howling ,then  does it mean I have hurt no one ?

Can it be that "convention" and "practical concept" are two ways to say the same thing?

A convention is a shallow concept. It is merely a name indicator. A practical idea can have practical consequences. Question is have I hurt no one in the above example ?

Let us continue this conversation in chat

Hm, well… These are phrases used to convey an understanding that cannot be properly expressed in language. Hold the words lightly, until understanding comes and washes them away…
If I may use an analogy, imagine a cup filled with water. The cup breaks and the water spills over the table, but it still exists; over the day the spill dries to vapor, but it still exists; over the night the vapor condenses to dew, but it still exists. This is the nature of reality, which entails constant flux from one state to another to another. We make cups so that we can pause or slow that transition, but it's an illusion to think we can stop or control it entirely.
Whenever we put a label or a name on something, we are making what might be thought of as a mental cup to hold onto what is constantly changing. When we call ourselves a name, we make a cup to hold ourselves constant; when we speak of living beings we make cups to hold those we interact with constant; when we talk about the dharma we've made a cup to hold the Buddha's understanding of the world constant. But all those things stretch beyond the cups we've placed them in. The cups are static, what they hold is dynamic, and we will never be satisfied only grasping the cup.
We can have a bird in a cage, sure, but then we have to wonder how much the word 'bird' in itself is a kind of cage for something inexpressible. See what I mean?

+1 for the inexpressible aspect that is often badly underestimated. Quoting verbatim without the penetrating insights is like trying to recreate a dish. Looks the same but the smell and taste is another thing.


All beings consist of causes and effects,
In which there is no ‘sentient being’ at all.
From phenomena which are exclusively empty,
There arise only empty phenomena.
All things are devoid of any ‘I’ or ‘mine’. -Nagarjuna, "The Heart of Dependent Origination"
 
The self's existence or nonexistence
Has in no way been established. -Nagarjuna, "Mulamadhyamakakarika"
 
As he attends inappropriately... one of six kinds of view arises in him: The view I have a self arises in him as true & established, or the view I have no self... -MN 2
 
The deepest teaching of Prājñāpāramitā is the emptiness of self and the emptiness of dharma and not the non-being of self and dharma. ... It is like a flower that is made only of non-flower elements. The flower is empty of a separate existence, but that doesn’t mean that the flower is not there. -Heart Sutra commentary, Thich Nhat Hanh


The following sutta quote is quite self-explanatory (and that's with pun intended).
It clearly shows that sentient beings are not real and actual (saccato thetato).

Then, in the evening, the Venerable Sāriputta emerged from seclusion.
He approached the Venerable Yamaka and exchanged greetings with him,
after which he sat down to one side and said to him: “Is it true,
friend Yamaka, that such a pernicious view as this has arisen in you:
‘As I understand the Dhamma taught by the Blessed One, a bhikkhu whose
taints are destroyed is annihilated and perishes with the breakup of
the body and does not exist after death’?”
“Exactly so, friend.”
“What do you think, friend Yamaka, is form permanent or
impermanent?”—“Impermanent, friend.”…—“Therefore … Seeing thus … He
understands: ‘… there is no more for this state of being.’
“What do you think, friend Yamaka, do you regard form as the
Tathagata?”—“No, friend.”—“Do you regard feeling … perception …
volitional formations … consciousness as the Tathagata?”—“No, friend.”
“What do you think, friend Yamaka, do you regard the Tathagata as in
form?”—“No, friend.”—“Do you regard the Tathagata as apart from
form?”—“No, friend.”—“Do you regard the Tathagata as in feeling? As
apart from feeling? As in perception? As apart from perception? As in
volitional formations? As apart from volitional formations? As in
consciousness? As apart from consciousness?”—“No, friend.”
“What do you think, friend Yamaka, do you regard form, feeling,
perception, volitional formations, and consciousness taken together as
the Tathagata?”—“No, friend.”
“What do you think, friend Yamaka, do you regard the Tathagata as one
who is without form, without feeling, without perception, without
volitional formations, without consciousness?”—“No, friend.”
“But, friend, when the Tathagata is not apprehended by you as
real and actual (saccato thetato) here
in this very life,
is it fitting for you to declare: ‘As I
understand the Dhamma taught by the Blessed One, a bhikkhu whose
taints are destroyed is annihilated and perishes with the breakup of
the body and does not exist after death’?”
“Formerly, friend Sāriputta, when I was ignorant, I did hold that
pernicious view, but now that I have heard this Dhamma teaching of the
Venerable Sāriputta I have abandoned that pernicious view and have
made the breakthrough to the Dhamma.”
SN 22.85


Verse 279 of the Dhammapada says: "All conditioned things are impermanent" (which implies that what we consider to be "self" is also impermanent) followed by verse 280 "All conditioned things are unsatisfactory" (suggesting that clinging to a "self" leads to suffering. Additionally, science can't prove the existence of an individual consciousness or mind, or even a seat of consciousness.

Sentient beings are sentient because they are aware when they experience pain, pleasure, joy, sadness and so on. Understanding that which experience i.e. all of us; is not of independent nature, does not have absolute control and is subjected to change; does not remove the desire to only experience happiness and not suffer any pain. Thus, the inherent importance of experiencing to all sentient beings.
Just as denying that pain exists, do not erase the experience of pain. Denying that an independent ‘I’ or ‘self’ exists, do not eliminate the experiencing of joy and happiness. It is for this reason that Nirvana makes sense. Otherwise, the search for Nirvana is totally unnecessary if experiencing is, inherently, non-existent.
Similarly, arahants are also not indifferent to experiencing. They would rather avoid unpleasant experiences. In the sutras, we read about arahants such as Ven. Vakkali and Ven. Channa who decided to enter Parinirvana early due to the unbearable pain brought about by their illnesses.
For arahants who have one-way tickets out of samsara, their experiencing of pain/suffering/misery end and the experiencing of the ultimate bliss begin once they enter Parinirvana. Unfortunately, this is not the case for the non-enlightened. As the Buddha pointed out to Ven. Aṅgulimāla in MN86:

“Bear with it, brahman! Bear with it! The fruit of the kamma that would have burned you in hell for many years, many hundreds of years, many thousands of years, you are now experiencing in the here & now!”

Thus, as long as we are stuck in samsara, our experiencing is a result of karma and bounded. Anything that is karma bounded is conditional i.e. anatta, anicca and dukkha. It is knowing that all experiencing in samsara is conditioned (and inherently empty) that an unbounded and unconditioned experiencing brought about by the Deathless becomes all the more important.
